# How to use method collection changed of Auto complete

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, sql-server-2008

I tried to use auto complete functionality in C# using SUBSTRING searches by many ways. Ends up with same problem all time. My logic does return the right set of information every time, but I am unable to display it right on time (changing available drop down in real time)

Like typing 'A' fills the drop down with

```
Adeel Nazir
Abdul Muqeet
Aun Abbas
```

Then I erase 'A' and retype 'N'. My code then executes and DOES return

```
Adeel Nazir
Aun Abbas
```

but my drop down is not updated.

I tried refreshing text field and many other ways..

Note: I also used functions instead of running query every time to search substring. But the main problem is to update drop down every time.

```
private void key_up(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     mycollection.Clear(); // autocompletecustomsource
     this.hostName.Refresh();

     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connection.con))
     {
        string cmd = " select hFirst+' '+hLast as Name from Hosts where hFirst+' '+hLast like '%" + this.hostName.Text + "%'";
        con.Open();

        using (command = new SqlCommand(cmd, con))
        {
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                mycollection.Add(reader["Name"].ToString());
            }

            hostName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = mycollection;
        }

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Editing:

Now after much of research I reached to a point that WE CAN edit our collection by collection changed method (default provided) but now I can't figure out a simple way to use it. Below is my new code executed on `key_up` event. Please guide me a bit on how to use collection changed method of autocomplete.

New code:

```html
private void key_up(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   mycollection.CollectionChanged+= mycollection.Add("abcd");
}
```

Comment: Can you also post your xaml? At least the part that TextBox and DropDown reside

Comment: there is no drop down. the text box shows the drop down when someone types in. Using Autocomplete custom source. Okay i am posting the xaml (by editing the post)

Comment: How can I get xaml code in windows form visual studio ultimate 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well out of this all confusion. I found an easy way out.
Just clear the autocomplete every time and add new items to it.
Simplest and fast enough

//autocomplete.clear();
autocomplete.add("name");